# Adding Image to existing PDF DO NOT replace the whole PDF

Tags: asp.net, itext, pdf-generation

I have this Code that adds image to a PDF:

```
     string SRC = 
            @"C:/Saved/Test.pdf";
        string DEST = @"C:/Saved/TestComplete.pdf";
        string IMG = @"C:Saved//TestImage.JPG";


    Document doc = new Document();

try
{
            iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream(SRC, FileMode.Create));
doc.Open();

//doc.Add(new Paragraph("GIF"));
iTextSharp.text.Image image = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(IMG);
    image.ScalePercent(200f);
doc.Add(image);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
            //Log error; 
            string error = ex.Message;
}
finally
{
doc.Close();
}
}
```

The Problem is here that its not just adding the image its replacing the whole PDF with that image is there a way to add a image in PDF just a signature image just add that to the page 
Any Idea ?
Also I have upgraded the Itextsharp to IText7 but I couldn't find a way to add image to a existing PDF only there are water marks. If you know a example Link or article on it please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If  you want to use the old method then use this:

```
   string SRC = 
            @"C:/Saved/Test.pdf";
        string DEST = @"C:/Saved/TestComplete.pdf";
        string IMG = @"C:Saved//TestImage.JPG";
 iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader reader = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader(SRC);
        iTextSharp.text.Rectangle Size = reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(1);
        Document document = new Document(Size);
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(DEST, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
        iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter weiter = iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, fs);
        document.Open();
        PdfContentByte cb = weiter.DirectContent;
        PdfImportedPage page = weiter.GetImportedPage(reader, 1);
        cb.AddTemplate(page, 0, 0);
        iTextSharp.text.Image jpg = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(IMG);
        document.Add(jpg);
        document.Close();
        fs.Close();
        weiter.Close();
        reader.Close();
```

For your question to use the iText7 method plesae refer  to this link [IText7 JumpStart](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-jump-start-tutorial/examples)

and to be exactly where you can find an example of dealing with images Please refer to this [Chapter7](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-jump-start-tutorial/examples/chapter-7)

I also recommend that you read all the chapters